# Print number of processed files in python

Tags: python, biopython

I want to print an argument about the number of files processed by the following code:

```
import sys
import re
import os
import fileinput
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
directory = os.getcwd()
def process(directory):
    filelist = os.listdir(directory)
    for f in filelist:
        if not f.endswith('.fastq'):
           continue
        SeqIO.convert(f, 'fastq', f[:-len('.fastq')]+'.fasta', 'fasta', alphabet=IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)

my_directory = os.getcwd()
process(my_directory)
```

Comment: Could you be clearer?

Comment: the script converts fastq files to fasta, and I want to have the number of files that have been converted by that SeqIO.convert command

Comment: There are packages out there such as [progressbar2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar2) that can give you a pretty output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to print the number of files converted? Do you mean like this?

```
import sys
import re
import os
import fileinput
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
directory = os.getcwd()

def process(directory):
    filelist = os.listdir(directory)
    files_processed = 0
    for f in filelist:
        if not f.endswith('.fastq'):
           continue
        SeqIO.convert(f, 'fastq', f[:-len('.fastq')]+'.fasta', 'fasta', alphabet=IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)
        files_processed += 1

    return files_processed

my_directory = os.getcwd()
files_processed = process(my_directory)
print(files_processed)
```